# pass long string to wcf bebservice

Tags: c#, wcf

For testing I have a little selfhosted webservice that returns the length of a submitted string.

It works fine with strings shorter or equal 32767 but loger strings are cut off.
I am testing with WCFtestclient and also adjusted the buffers in the client config.But it seems to be ignored. Found a lot of samples with IIS hosted services that just increase the buffers and it seems to work. in selfhosting it seems that it does not.

This is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="NewBinding0" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered"
                    messageEncoding="Text">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                                  maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                                  maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                                  maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                                  maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>

                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://CELSIUS:8080/RWService/RWService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
                contract="RWOrderServiceWCF.IRWWCFService" name="testclient"
                kind="" endpointConfiguration="">
                <identity>
                    <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                        x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="NewBehavior0">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior0" name="RWOrderServiceWCF.RWWCFService">
                <endpoint address="RWService.svc" binding="basicHttpContextBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="" contract="RWOrderServiceWCF.IRWWCFService"
                    isSystemEndpoint="false" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://CELSIUS:8080/RWService" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you can't find a fix for this and you can change contract I'd suggest to think to use a Stream instead of a property for such _big_ objects.

Comment: Thanks Adriano! I know that streaming could be a solution. Also cutting the string in pieces and send multible requests would be possible. But my strings are arround 80-90 k and I'd like to know if there is a string size limit in self hosting.

Comment: I don't know, I'll wait for answers to this question!

Comment: Can you please include your Message or Data Contract definitions. This may be the problem. If you're packing your string unintentionally into the header of the message, you could be running into the length limit of the header, but if you're using the body of the message to transport your string, it's something else.

Comment: cannot post the message as it is too long, but the message is in the body and cut off after 32767. Seems it is the client that cuts off. But also the client has the same settings for maxStringlength...

Comment: I reconfigured my service and took out the endpoint address. Now the service works also with large strings.

Comment: The Problem was following line:            <endpoint address="RWService.svc" binding="basicHttpContextBinding" after changing to endpoint address ="" and basicHttpContextBinding to basicHttpBinding everything works fine.